# Как отфильтровать relationship rows в flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть 2 связаные таблицы, подскажите как нужно связать модели и сделать запрос для того чтоб получить First по key в котором Second будет отфильтровано по необходимому language.

```
    class First(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'first'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        key = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)

        second = db.relationship("Second")

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<First %r>' % self.key

    class Second(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'second'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        language = db.Column(db.String(6), nullable=False)
        title = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)

        first_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('first.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
        first = db.relationship('First', backref='second_firsts', foreign_keys=[first_id])

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Second %r>' % self.id
```

При:

```
Cv.query.filter(Cv.key == key).first()
```

Я получаю:

```
    {
        "key": "firts",
        "second": [
            {
                "language": "eng",
                "title": "EngTitle"
            },
            {
                "language": "rus",
                "title": "RusTitle"
            }
        ]
    }
```

А хотелось бы с отфильтрованым language.

Answer (score 0):

```
first = First.query.filter(First.key == key).first() # получаем first по key
second = first.second # записываем в second все объекты second, связанные с first
filter_second = list(filter(lambda sec: sec.language == 'eng', second)) 
# функция filter проходится lambda-функцией по каждому элементу из second 
# и записывает в filter_second, если выполняется условие sec.language == 'eng'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, коротко поясните предложенное решение. Ответ можно поправить кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1103129/edit).